# Access Geoserver From Internet Ubuntu Server 14.04.1

Tags: apache2, tomcat7, geoserver, ubuntu-14.04

i'm triying to getup geoserver on IBM Server with Ubuntu Server 14.04.1, i have try making a file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/geoserver.conf and the information in it was:

`ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"`

I access to my server via a subdomain in NO-IP, but a i can't make it work the geoserver, like this; my.subdomain.com/geoserver

A will give any information you need, i really need some help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a lot of research and try lot of things, I understood where I have to put this lines, to set up ProxyPass for GeoServer public data access:

```
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPreserveHost On 
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow 
        Allow from all
</Proxy> 
ProxyPass /geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver" 
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"
```

In almost every tutorial that I read, they all explain how to access via internet to GeoServer, using httpd sever, where you have to add the lines of ProxyPass in the archive httpd.conf, in the route:

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

But since I'm using apache2 server instead of the httpd server, the code to use ProxyPass must be put in in the file 000-default.conf and the route is:

/etc/apache2/sites-avaible/000-default.conf

The code have to be between the labels:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         "some code and comments"
         ProxyRequests Off
         ProxyPreserveHost On
         <Proxy *>
              Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
         </Proxy>
         ProxyPass /geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"
         ProxyPassReverse /geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps.

Any errors you see from me feel free to comment.

Greetings to all.

Comment: Hi Diego,I have also same problem,I tried your code but not working.I have tomcat 8 on localhost:8080,Apache 2 on localhost and geoserver on localhost:8080/geoserver/.I want geoserver link as localhost/geoserver in Ubuntu 16.4.I dont know whats wrong with me "internal server error is coming 500".Thanks

Comment: Could you post the logs from the server, to see why you 've got that 500 error. The apache logs. Did you create in hosts that direction, localhost/geoserver?

Comment: Thanks diego for reply,My problem solved  some proxy_http enabled.Thanks